# $\operatorname{ord}_p(\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}T(\overline i)^{p-1-k}\psi(\overline i))=?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, prime-numbers, finite-fields, p-adic-number-theory

Let $Z_p$ denote the p-adic integers. Let $T:\mathbb{F_p}\to Z_p$ be a function with the following properties:

1. $\forall x \in \mathbb{F}_p[\overline {T(x)}=x]$
2. $\forall x \in \mathbb{F}_p[T(x)^p=T(x)]$

Let $\psi: \mathbb{F}_p \to Z_p(\zeta_p)$ have the following properties:

1. $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{F}_p[\psi(x+y)=\psi(x)\psi(y)]$
2. $\exists x \in \mathbb{F}_p[\psi(x) \neq 1]$

Moreover, assume $1 \leq k \leq p-2$.

By the way, the \overline notation indicates reduction mod p.

> I want to find the p-adic order of $\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}T(\overline i)^{p-1-k}\psi(\overline i)$

---

I have been able to find for the special case $p=3$ and $k=1$ using an ad-hoc method. In the special case, I use the fact that $T(\overline 2)=-1$ and the sum becomes $\psi(1)-\psi(2)=\psi(1)[1-\psi(1)],$ which has p-order $\frac 1 {p-1}=\frac 1 2$ by [this theorem.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3030429/proving-ord-p%CE%B6-p-1-1-p-1) But I don't see how to solve the general case. My professor thinks that the order in the general case should be $\frac k {p-1}$ but, alas, I don't see why.

Comment: Let $f$ a function $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \to K$ such that $f(lm) = f(l)f(m)$ and $a \in K$ then

$G_a(k) = \sum_{l=1}^{p} f(l) a^{lk} = f(k^{-1})\sum_{l=1}^{p} f(lk) a^{lk}=f(k^{-1}) G_a(1)$.

If $a^p = 1, a \ne 1$ then 

$\sum_{k=1}^p a^{-mk} G_a(k) =\sum_{l=1}^{p} f(l) \sum_{k=1}^pa^{(l-m)k} =  p f(m)$

Whence $p = p f(1)=\sum_{k=1}^p a^{-k} G_a(k)=\sum_{k=1}^p a^{-k} f(k^{-1}) G_a(1) = G_a(1)^*G_a(1) $  where $*$ is the map sending a root of unity $\zeta$ to $\zeta^{-1}$. If $K = \mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_p),a = \zeta_p$ then $|G_a(1)^*|_p = |G_a(1)|_p =|p^{1/2}|_p = p^{-1/2}$.

Comment: @reuns: Why not post that as an answer?